# How can I send POST request using command line HeadlessChrome (Not selenium)

Tags: cmd, http-post, headless, google-chrome-headless

I'm trying to send a POST request using HeadlessChrome.
Searched in Google and here.

Could find only this post - https://peter.sh/experiments/chromium-command-line-switches/

It shows Chrome's flags, and --method flag.

I tried a few variations of the --method flag, and searched for it with no luck.

I'm want to run this command:

```
.\chrome.exe --headless --method POST http://www.SomeWebSite.com
```

Thanks!

Comment: Have you managed how to send a POST request?